# MATLAB: Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals

Tags: matlab

Getting this error message:"Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals". Not really sure why? I've attempted correcting it with no success. Do i need to write out the numeric values I am trying to use in my calculation?

```
function [ T,P,rho ] = stdatm( h );
T0=288.16;
P0=101.325;
rho0=1.225;
a=-6.5*10^-3;
b=3*10^-3;
c=-4.5*10^-3;
d=4.0*10^-3;
R=286.9;
g=9.81;

T1=T0+a*11000;
P1=P0(T1/T0)^(-g/(a/R));
rho1=rho0(T1/T0)^((-g/(a/R))-1);
```

Comment: You must have zeros or non-integers in your variable you're trying to use as an index. It's impossible to say without seeing your code.

Comment: What Suever said, Matlab indices start from 1 .

Comment: can you give me an example? I have my code above?

Comment: When you write 'P0(T1/T0)' matlab thinks P0  is array (or function, if array not exist) that you try to access with index T1/T0. So to multiply write: 'P0*(T1/T0) '

Answer (score 3):

You're probably missing an operator (times `*`?):

```
P1=P0(T1/T0)^(-g/(a/R));
%    ^
rho1=rho0(T1/T0)^((-g/(a/R))-1);
%        ^
```

Here you are indexing `P0` and `rho0` with `T1/T0`

Comment: adding to @O'Neils answer. If you don't write the multiplication sign, Matlab tries to acces the array `P0` with the index `T1/T0`. This ratio however is something like ` 0.751`... so it is no integer or logical.